# Lag command that self-references itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag

I'm looking to use the LAG function to fill a field repeatedly down the length of a table's contents.  Here's my situation. I'm reading data from a clumsy source that pulls rows that look like this --

```
Split_Name_In_Heading         ID
Central Scheduling (contd)    171081
NULL                          171083
NULL                          171088
NULL                          171091
NULL                          171094
NULL                          171097
```

There's thousands of these, where I have the field I'm interested in grabbing, the Split_Name_In_Heading, and cascading it down through all the records that follow.  I want to do this until I hit a new Split_Name_In_Heading, and then start copying that one instead.  So I did this --

```
select
  case when Split_Name_In_Heading is null 
       then lag(Split_Name) over (order by ID)
       else REPLACE(SPLIT_NAME_IN_HEADING, ' (contd)', '') end as Split_Name,
  Split_Name_In_Heading,
  ID
--into #Pass_1
from #Clean_List
order by ID
```

Note that I'm trying to create a new field, Split_Name, that references the prior row's Split_Name.  It is self-referencing.  (It removes the junk on the end of the Split_Name_In_Heading field too, but that's fine)  My desired result --

```
Split_Name            Split_Name_In_Heading           ID
Central Scheduling    Central Scheduling (contd)      171081
Central Scheduling    NULL                            171083
Central Scheduling    NULL                            171088
Central Scheduling    NULL                            171091
Central Scheduling    NULL                            171094
Central Scheduling    NULL                            171097
```

My code is producing an error.  I can't reference the field Split_Name in the definition of the field Split_Name.  When I try to use Split_Name_In_Heading to boot-load the value for a second pass it only creates the value for one following record.  After that the values remain null.

This is a conversion from WebFOCUS code where this is a super-easy thing that we've done dozens of times in our code base, so I'm looking for a general solution.  I need to replace all of it.  Can LAG self-reference its own field somehow?  I've seen a couple of threads that use a temp table and references by prior row, but I haven't figured out an easy way to make that work yet because they don't continue to copy the value down the set of multiple rows that have nulls.  It can be up to 100 sometimes.

Comment: `LAG` can't reference its prior iterations. If you need to do something like that you need iteration/recursion.

Comment: REPRESENTATIVE sample data is better - ie sample should include 'until I hit a new Split_Name_In_Heading'

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Is the data in `Split_Name_In_Heading` separated by `NULLS`?
If so then is a last not null problem - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7379/last-non-null-value-set-of-sql-server-records/

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you need is the `LAST_VALUE()` window function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option.

*The IGNORE NULLS option is only available in SQL Server 2022 and later, so this solution cannot be used with earlier versions.*

```
select
    last_value(replace(Split_Name_In_Heading, ' (contd)', ''))
        ignore nulls
        over(order by ID)  -- Range unbounded preceding is implied
        as Split_Name,
    Split_Name_In_Heading,
    ID
from #Clean_List
order by ID
```

Results (with some extra data):

| Split_Name | Split_Name_In_Heading | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Central Scheduling | Central Scheduling (contd) | 171081 |
| Central Scheduling | *null* | 171083 |
| Central Scheduling | *null* | 171088 |
| Central Scheduling | *null* | 171091 |
| Central Scheduling | *null* | 171094 |
| Central Scheduling | *null* | 171097 |
| Pharmacy | Pharmacy (contd) | 172001 |
| Radiology | Radiology (contd) | 172002 |
| Radiology | *null* | 172003 |
| Radiology | *null* | 172004 |
| Radiology | *null* | 172005 |

This can also be wrapped up as a subquery or CTE and fed to an update statement.

```
update S
set Split_Name_In_Heading = replace(Split_Name, ' (contd)', '')
from (
    select
        last_value(Split_Name_In_Heading)
            ignore nulls
            over(order by ID)  -- Range unbounded preceding is implied
            as Split_Name,
        Split_Name_In_Heading,
        ID
    from #Clean_List
) S
```

The above also moves the `REPLACE()` to the `SET` clause.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ke9GySyK).

Comment: IGNORE NULLs !!!!  I zoom past this one all the time!  +1

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, it's faster and may be more correct.

Comment: @Charlieface - I believe ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is the default whenever an ORDER BY is specified and no ROWS specification is given.  (If no ORDER BY is given, the default is all rows in the result group.) Most often used for the running sum or running count uses, but also applies here.  I'll add a comment to the code though.

Comment: Good 2022 solution, probably worth mentioning it's only 2022+ though

Comment: @Stu - Good catch. The documentation threw me off. The [2016 LAST_VALUE() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) showed IGNORE NULLS in the syntax, and I didn't see the version note further down. I didn't know older version documentation would reference newer version features.

Comment: @TN but it does state *Applies to: SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2022 (16.x)), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, Azure SQL Edge*

Comment: @Charlieface I am not understanding what "subtly different" behaviors you are referring to. I can find no documented or observable difference between **ROWS** and **RANGE**. Documentation states that "**CURRENT ROW** is used for the boundary ending point" for the *short syntax* "**xxx PRECEDING**" form. I am getting the same expected results for all of the following: `OVER(ORDER BY Id)`, `OVER(ORDER BY Id ROWS/RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`, and `OVER(ORDER BY Id ROWS/RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`.  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7i2H08B1). Am I missing something?

Comment: I like this!  It's clear that LAG is the wrong command.  LAST_VALUE is the way to go.

Comment: I'll also mention that I created a solution with a subselect inside a subselect, which in theory should be slow as dirt.  But with an indexed ID field it was stoopid fast for 60,000 records.  I couldn't even detect the lag between pressing the button and seeing the results.  .  But Last_Value seems much neater.  .  Thank you all!

Comment: @Charlieface - Got it. So range is kind of like a *with-ties* behavior.  FOr the above, it should not make a difference if the order fully specified and is unambiguous.  If there are duplicate ID values, the data has bigger problems. I changed the comment above to properly state "*Range*  unbounded preceding is implied".

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "it's faster and *may be* more correct" as it depends if the ordering has duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is the SEQUENCE here, we can use the window function `sum() over ()` to create a grouping, then then we use the window function `max() over()` for the final value

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Split_Name_In_Heading] varchar(50),[ID] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Central Scheduling (cont''d)',171081)
,(NULL,171083)
,(NULL,171088)
,(NULL,171091)
,(NULL,171094)
,(NULL,171097)
,('Other Item (cont''d)',181081)  -- added another example
,(NULL,181083);                   -- added another example
 

with cte as (
Select *
      ,Flg = sum(case when [Split_Name_In_Heading] is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ID)
 from @YourTable
)
Select Split_Name = replace(max([Split_Name_In_Heading]) over (partition by Flg),' (cont''d)','')
      ,[Split_Name_In_Heading]
      ,ID
 From cte
 Order by ID
```

**Results**

```
Split_Name          Split_Name_In_Heading       ID
Central Scheduling  Central Scheduling (cont'd) 171081
Central Scheduling  NULL                        171083
Central Scheduling  NULL                        171088
Central Scheduling  NULL                        171091
Central Scheduling  NULL                        171094
Central Scheduling  NULL                        171097
Other Item          Other Item (cont'd)         181081
Other Item          NULL                        181083
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, it's faster and may be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a simple correlated subquery here as a table expression that you can then update.

Example:

```
update t set 
  name = NewName
from (
    select *, (
        select top(1) name 
        from t t2
        where t2.name is not null and t2.id < t.id
        order by id desc
    ) NewName
    from t
    where name is null
)t;
```

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ff005ex-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative version that i prefer to use, which uses less window functions, the downside is a bit more complicated code:

```sql
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE ([Split_Name_In_Heading] varchar(50),[ID] int)
INSERT INTO @YourTable
VALUES ('Central Scheduling (cont''d)',171081)
,(NULL,171083)
,(NULL,171088)
,(NULL,171091)
,(NULL,171094)
,(NULL,171097)
,('Other Item (cont''d)',181081)
,(NULL,181083);
 
SELECT  *
,   STUFF(
   MAX(
     RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20)), 20) + Split_Name_In_Heading
    ) OVER(ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    , 1, 20, '') AS GroupedHeading
FROM    @YourTable
```

Explanation:

We want to get the maximum value which helps us remove NULLs, but it has to be sorted by ID. For this reason, i create a padded string which consists of ID and Header, something like:

| Split_Name_In_Heading | Padded string |
| --- | --- |
| Central Scheduling (cont'd) | 00000000000000171081Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| Other Item (cont'd) | 00000000000000181081Other Item (cont'd) |

The `RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20)), 20)` padding takes care of integers with different lengths.

Finally, we're ready to get the maximum value by using the `MAX(...) OVER()` window function. But this gets us the padded string, so `STUFF(..., 1, 20, '')` removes the padding.

Final output:

| Split_Name_In_Heading | ID | GroupedHeading |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Central Scheduling (cont'd) | 171081 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| NULL | 171083 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| NULL | 171088 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| NULL | 171091 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| NULL | 171094 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| NULL | 171097 | Central Scheduling (cont'd) |
| Other Item (cont'd) | 181081 | Other Item (cont'd) |
| NULL | 181083 | Other Item (cont'd) |

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with which is likely completely SQL standard --

```
create nonclustered index idx on #Clean_List (ID)
select
       ID,
       (select REPLACE(SPLIT_NAME_IN_HEADING, ' (cont''d)', '') 
          from #Clean_List middle 
          where middle.ID = 
             (select max(ID) 
                from #Clean_List max 
                where SPLIT_NAME_IN_HEADING is not null 
                  and max.ID < CL.ID)) 
          as Split_Name,
       Split_Name_In_Heading,
from #Clean_List CL
order by ID
```

This ran 60,000 records super-fast with an index on the ID field.  On a temp table no less.  But the Last_Value solutions look cleaner.